# Database Model Table for each Relationship?

Tags: hibernate, database-design, jpa

I have a question modelling a relationship in my database.

I have a table "comment" and three tables "user", "car", "house". Every user can comment on user, cars and houses.

Normally this would result in a relationship where all fks are hold in table "comment" like car_id, house_id, user_id. But these relationships are exclusive so its not possible to have a comment which belongs to a car and house.

Is it wise now to have all the fks in the comment table? So if we want to extend(e.g. comments on pictures) it could result in a lot of nullable fks.

Or is it a good choice to have a new table for each relationship like "UserComment", "CarComment" and "HouseComment".

I hope this is not a duplicate but I found it very hard to search this issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the answer by Roman, it does not necessarily have to be the table name.  Really the idea there is that of a discriminator.

So in terms of tables, this would look like:

```
create table house ( id .., ..., primary key (id) )
create table user ( id .., ..., primary key (id) )
create table car ( id .., ..., primary key (id) )
create table comment( id ..., commenter ..., commented_id ..., commented_type ... )
```

There are a few ways you could apply discrimination to such a set of relationships.

First is that you could make Comment itself be a hierarchy and use discriminator-based subclassing.  The cons of this approach are that the subclasses are completely worthless, serving only the needs of the persistence.  The pro of this approach is that it would work with any JPA provider.  To use this approach you'd have:

```
@Entity
@Table( name="comment" )
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="commented_type")
public abstract class Comment {
    @Id
    @Column( name="id" )
    private Long id;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class HouseComment extends Comment {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="commented_id")
    private House getHouse();
    ...
}

etc...
```

Like I said, kind of fugly.

Hibernate, specifically gives you other options to handle this.  For example, using its concept of an "any" mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table( name="comment" )
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @Column( name="id" )
    private Long id;

    @Any( metaColumn = @Column( name="commented_type" ) )
    @AnyMetDef(
        idType = "long"
        metaValues = {
            @MetaValue( value="C", targetEntity=Carclass ),
            @MetaValue( value="H", targetEntity=House.class ),
            @MetaValue( value="U", targetEntity=User.class )
        }
    )
    pubic Commentable getCommentTarget { ... }
}

public interface Commentable {
    ...
}

@Entity
public House implements Commentable {
   ...
}

etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid redundancy and not necessary nulls in your db I would suggest the use of inheritance, if it's possible in db you use. Then you create parent table named 'commented_objects' or something like that and 3 tables that inherit from parent table with the same incrementing sequence. 
In this situation you need only one referencing table between parent and comments table.

You can simulate inheritance if your db doesn't allow it by using composition and common sequence.

So the code gonna look like (for PostgreSQL):

```
CREATE TABLE commented_objects(
    id int,
    comment text
);


CREATE TABLE cars(
    some_fields text
) INHERITS (commented_objects);


CREATE TABLE houses(
    some_fields text
) INHERITS (commented_objects);

CREATE TABLE users(
    some_fields text
) INHERITS (commented_objects);

CREATE TABLE ref_table(
    id int,
    comment_id
);
```

You can easily expand the structure if you want to by adding new inherited table.